# Data Segregation in Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

We have a SaaS service that is hosting data from multiple clients.  We are trying to use Aamzon's CloudSearch to provide document searching against all the hosted data.

One feature we are trying to make work is the "suggest" feature, where user can type in a few letters, and Amazon CloudSearch will allow user to auto-complete with likely search terms.

However, I would like the suggest feature to only suggest search terms based on one particular client (or tenant, to be technically correct).  I don't want the search suggestions to prompt user from tenant A, with keywords that are based on the docuemnts from tenant Z.  Is there a way to "segregate" the data in a single Search Domain, so that each client/tenant's data is tagged in a way so that, the "suggest" feature will leverage the data from the matching client/tenant?

(I can use API to filter the search result based on the tenant, but the suggest API doesn't have a way to apply filter)

Comment: I ended up just using the search API, because the suggest API was so limiting.  As long as you only return the fields you need for suggestions, the response time is very similar to suggest API, and you have so much more flexibility.